# How can I implement a promise in my calculator function?

Tags: javascript, promise

I've written a calculator-like application in JavaScript, mainly so that it will run in any browser. It has a number of input fields. When I press the calculate button, it gathers data from these fields, calls various functions on it, and displays the result. There's no asynchronous stuff to do, no web or disc fetches that could delay or fail, the user triggers an event and then has to wait until the answer has been produced.

The fragment below is more or less a Hello World for this sort of process.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function transformer(instring)
{
    var outstring = instring + instring;
    return outstring;
}

function calculate()
{
    var srcStr = document.mainform.src.value;
    var transformed = transformer(srcStr);
    document.mainform.dst.value = transformed; 
}
</script>

<form name="mainform">
Input data <input type="text" name="src" value="abc"/><br>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:calculate();">Calculate</button><br>
Output data <input type="text" name="dst"  />
</form>
```

I would like to replace the transformer() function with a function from a library that returns a promise. What's the minimum change in code I need to make to accomplish this. I've searched a lot for promises, async functions, thens etc, but not found a simple 'here is how to use a promise in a simple event driven program', and I have not yet managed to write a working equivalent of the program above. Once I have a working hello world, I can build from there.

Assume that the promise will always resolve, reject never needs to be handled. By 'minimum change', I don't necessarily mean fewest characters, but easiest to understand, or with fewest new concepts.

Comment: First step return a promise, second step, use it.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, I've read that several times in my searches, and seen it in code that has additional features I don't understand or think I need. What would it look like in the above code if transformer() returned a promise rather than a prompt value?

Comment: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(whatYouWantToReturn);
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a promise, you call `.then` on it and specify what code you want to run once the value is available:

```
function transformer(instring)
{
  var outstring = instring + instring;
  return Promise.resolve(outstring);
}

function calculate()
{
  var srcStr = document.mainform.src.value;
  transformer(srcStr)
    .then(transformed => {
      document.mainform.dst.value = transformed; 
    });
}
```

Alternatively, if async/await is an option you can use the await keyword in an async function. The await keyword will pause your function and wait until the promise resolves, and then resume your code. This can make for cleaner syntax, but promises are still involved.

```
async function calculate()
{
    var srcStr = document.mainform.src.value;
    var transformed = await transformer(srcStr);
    document.mainform.dst.value = transformed; 
}
```

Comment: The await construction looks very useful. But you say 'if it is an option'. When might it not be? This will only be run on new(ish) browsers. Might there anything in the library function that would prevent the use of await in the calling code? How would I inspect for that?

Comment: async/await is a fairly recent addition to the language. Modern browsers support it, but older ones will not. You can see details of what supports it here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions . If you do need to run on those browsers, you can still write code using async await, but your build process will need to have a step which transpiles it into older code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `transformer` returns a promise, that resolves with the transformed string:

```
function calculate() {
    var srcStr = document.mainform.src.value;
    transformer(srcStr).then(function (transformed) {
        document.mainform.dst.value = transformed;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code using a promise. Note the result side.

```js
function transformer(instring) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const outstring = instring + instring;
    resolve(outstring);
  });
}

function calculate() {
  var srcStr = document.querySelector('#src').value;
  transformer(srcStr).then(result => document.querySelector('#dst').value = result);
}
```

```html
<form name="mainform">
  Input data <input type="text" id="src" value="abc" /><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="javascript:calculate();">Calculate</button><br> Output data <input type="text" id="dst" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to make `transformer` an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) it inside calculate (which would also need to be an `async` function).

```js
async function transformer(instring) {
  var outstring = instring + instring;
  return outstring;
}

async function calculate() {
  var srcStr = document.mainform.src.value;
  var transformed = await transformer(srcStr);
  document.mainform.dst.value = transformed;
}
```

```html
<form name="mainform">
  Input data <input type="text" name="src" value="abc" /><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="javascript:calculate();">Calculate</button><br>
  Output data <input type="text" name="dst" />
</form>
```

Of course, this will only work on browsers that support this syntax ([which is any major browser released in 2017 or later](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions)). If you need to support the older Promise-based syntax, the above code is effectively identical to this:

```js
function transformer(instring) {
  var outstring = instring + instring;
  return Promise.resolve(outstring);
}

function calculate() {
  var srcStr = document.mainform.src.value;
  transformer(srcStr).then(function(transformed) {
    document.mainform.dst.value = transformed;
  });
}
```

```html
<form name="mainform">
  Input data <input type="text" name="src" value="abc" /><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="javascript:calculate();">Calculate</button><br>
  Output data <input type="text" name="dst" />
</form>
```

And of course, *this* will only work in browsers that support promises ([which is any major browser released in 2015 or later](https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises)), but you can use a library like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) to patch it in to most browsers that do not.